# add post data to an array in controller and output from view with Codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, post, view, controller

I have the following syntax:

**Contoller**

```
  function new_auto_spread_details() 
  {
      $postinfo = array();
      $postinfo[] = $this->input->post('customer')
      $postinfo[] = $this->input->post('period')      
      $this->load->view('sales/new_autospread_order_lines',$postinfo);
  }
```

**View**

```
<?php echo $postinfo['customer']; ?>
<?php echo $postinfo['period']; ?>
```

This does not output anything. it seems that adding `$this->input->post('customer')` to the array postinfo is not correct.

How do I correctly add this information to the postinfo array and call it from the view?

Thanks as always...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function new_auto_spread_details() 
  {
      $postinfo = array();
      $data['postinfo']['customer'] = $this->input->post('customer');
      $data['postinfo']['period'] = $this->input->post('period');     
      $this->load->view('sales/new_autospread_order_lines',$data);
  }
```

on view

```
<?php echo $postinfo['customer']; ?>
<?php echo $postinfo['period']; ?>
```